# Custom Bootstrap button now showing hover color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a custom Bootstrap button color from this site: http://blog.koalite.com/bbg/

From that site I got the following CSS:

```
 .btn-sample { 
  color: #ffffff; 
  background-color: #000000; 
  border-color: #030303; 
} 

.btn-sample:hover, 
.btn-sample:focus, 
.btn-sample:active, 
.btn-sample.active, 
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-sample { 
  color: #ffffff; 
  background-color: #A1A0A3; 
  border-color: #030303; 
} 

.btn-sample:active, 
.btn-sample.active, 
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-sample { 
  background-image: none; 
} 

.btn-sample.disabled, 
.btn-sample[disabled], 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-sample, 
.btn-sample.disabled:hover, 
.btn-sample[disabled]:hover, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-sample:hover, 
.btn-sample.disabled:focus, 
.btn-sample[disabled]:focus, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-sample:focus, 
.btn-sample.disabled:active, 
.btn-sample[disabled]:active, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-sample:active, 
.btn-sample.disabled.active, 
.btn-sample[disabled].active, 
fieldset[disabled] .btn-sample.active { 
  background-color: #000000; 
  border-color: #030303; 
} 

.btn-sample .badge { 
  color: #000000; 
  background-color: #ffffff; 
}
```

When I hover over the button, it shows the default almost grey color. I thought I would see the color in the backround-color **#A1A0A3**.

I do have this CSS style right before the button I want changed and it listed after the script include for bootstrap.css

Comment: What other classes do you have on the button? Sometimes the bootstrap btn classes have more priority. You can try adding `background-color: #A1A0A3 !important;` to see if this is the case.

Comment: Why don't you just debug it? You can activate `:hover` pseudo-class in developer tools (both Firefox and Chrome afaik support it), then check the cascade to see what's going on. Otherwise, it's really hard to tell without looking at the code (and essentially doing the same thing).

Comment: `#A1A0A3` is showing on hover as the background color with a thin black border. [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HeULwRbKmwz5DH9MZFdn?p=preview)